# How to encode in ASCII with parity

Tags: parity

The following question if from an old exam paper on computer organization.

"How many bits are needed to encode a typical textbook in ASCII with parity. How many CDROMs and how many DVDs are needed to store a library with 1 million book? Let us assume that the average textbook contains about 1 million characters including spaces "

My concern for now is only the first part of the question. Since ASCII is comprised of 7 bits, I assume you only have to add and additional parity bit hence making the answer 8 bits. Am I correct in assuming this?

P.S: This question doesn't have to do with error detection.

Comment: Right. It is always +1 when you want to include parity bits.

Comment: Each character would be X bits, I think a "typical textbook" is thousands of characters.  Can you clarify that in your question please?  :)

Comment: Someone will answer eventually - but as a side note, and to pre-empt a mistake, just remember that KB and kB are different things - KB = 1024, kB = 1000.

Comment: "Since ASCII is comprised of 8 bits" -> ASCII is comprised of 7 bits.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, you are correct. I didn't realize the last bits in the table was zero. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @DanRayson i should mention that a *kibibyte* (KiB) is also 1024 bytes

Answer (score 1):

I'll attempt to answer this myself. 
Each character uses 8 bits, (7 for ASCII plus a parity bit; see question). There are 1 000 000 characters in the average textbook hence 8 000 000 bits per textbook. A library comprised of 1 000 000 textbooks would require (8 000 000 * 1 000 000) = 8 * 10^12 bits.
According to my textbook a DVD can store 17 Gbytes hence 136 * 10^9 bits.
Therefore, (8*10^12)/136*10^9) = 59 DVDs required to stored the library.
Did I misstep?

Comment: You made me question it, but no, I think you did not misstep!